# Download PostgreSQL 10.4

Tags: postgresql

I have searched the interwebs for PostgreSQL 10.4 (32 & 64) for Linux platforms and Windows platforms but have been unable to locate any binaries to download.  All I can find is the 10.5 version (or 9.x).  Any ideas on where to look?

Thanks!

Comment: The difference from 10.4 to 10.5 is only a minor version (not like 9.4 to 9.5 but instead like 9.4.1 to 9.4.2) so just take the 10.5 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [Versioning policy](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/),
the rightmost number denotes the minor release, so `10.5` is the most recent release of PostgreSQL 10:

> Minor releases are numbered by increasing the last part of the
>   version number. Beginning with PostgreSQL 10, this is the second part
>   of the version number, e.g. 10.0 to 10.1; for older versions this is
>   the third part of the version number, e.g. 9.5.3 to 9.5.4

10.(x-1) is generally made unavailable as soon as 10.x is released, because 10.(x-1) is the same set of programs, but with known bugs not yet fixed: it should not be prefered over a more recent version.
In most cases, the will to install a specific outdated minor release is due to not knowing the version numbering policy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply!